# Iterate over image and select lightness/saturation values in a given hue range not using nested for loops

Tags: python, list, opencv

Story behind:
I am trying to build a simple hand detection that is adaptive to environmental changes (light mainly) and therefore re-calibrates every few minutes using a histogram of a rough estimate where the hand is (using YOLO-Darknet).
Idea is to get the finger position at the end.

Currently I am getting the hue value of the hand and the lightness and saturation are fixed.
I have written a short nested for loop for the lightness and saturation search where it goes through all the elements in the hue range and finds its max and min value to write it in the array.

Now my question:
I know that python has functionalities for writing such nested loops and list modification/manipulation short and elegant, how do I do this?

Following I have an MWE and an example image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

hue = 0
light = 1
satur = 2

img = cv2.imread('Untitled.png')
hls = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)


# structure of histograms:
# 0, 2, 6 = histogram values for H, L and S
# 1, 3, 5 = bin values for H, L and S
histograms = [0] * 6

# Only 5 bins for a rough estimate of the skin color (so not too much is lost)
histograms[0], histograms[1] = np.histogram(hls[:, :, 0], 5)
histograms[2], histograms[3] = np.histogram(hls[:, :, 1], 5)
histograms[4], histograms[5] = np.histogram(hls[:, :, 2], 5)

# structure of HLS_bins:
# [Hue, Lightness, Saturation]         [min, min, min]
# [Hue, Lightness, Saturation]         [max, max, max]
HLS_bins = [[0, 200, 30], [0, 255, 255]]

# TODO alternative approach to the one below:
# todo...find the bin for the highest occuring color and select the Lightness
# todo...and Saturation according to the corresponding values

#  write in loop (elegant/generalized way) ?
# select the highest occurence of the hue
max_value_hue = max(histograms[0])
max_index_hue = list(histograms[0]).index(max_value_hue)
HLS_bins[0][0] = histograms[1][max_index_hue]
HLS_bins[1][0] = histograms[1][max_index_hue + 1]

min_value_light = 255
max_value_light = 0
min_value_saturation = 255
max_value_saturation = 0

for row in range(np.shape(hls)[0]):
    for col in range(np.shape(hls)[1]):
        if hls[row][col][hue] > HLS_bins[0][0] and hls[row][col][hue] < HLS_bins[1][0]:
            if hls[row][col][light] > max_value_light:
                max_value_light = hls[row][col][light]
            if hls[row][col][light] < min_value_light:
                min_value_light = hls[row][col][light]
            if hls[row][col][satur] > max_value_saturation:
                max_value_saturation = hls[row][col][satur]
            if hls[row][col][satur] < min_value_saturation:
                min_value_saturation = hls[row][col][satur]

HLS_bins[0][1] = min_value_light
HLS_bins[1][1] = max_value_light
HLS_bins[0][2] = min_value_saturation
HLS_bins[1][2] = max_value_saturation

HLS_bins = np.array(HLS_bins, dtype="uint8")
print(HLS_bins)
```

[image: Test Image]

Most should have guessed it already, it's about this part of code:

```
for row in range(np.shape(hls)[0]):
        for col in range(np.shape(hls)[1]):
            if hls[row][col][hue] > HLS_bins[0][0] and hls[row][col][hue] < HLS_bins[1][0]:
                if hls[row][col][light] > max_value_light:
                    max_value_light = hls[row][col][light]
                if hls[row][col][light] < min_value_light:
                    min_value_light = hls[row][col][light]
                if hls[row][col][satur] > max_value_saturation:
                    max_value_saturation = hls[row][col][satur]
                if hls[row][col][satur] < min_value_saturation:
                    min_value_saturation = hls[row][col][satur]
```

So, how to write this nice and elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to obtain the max and min values of your Lightness and Saturation (the last 2 channels), a way of doing it is by using the `np.max()` and `np.min()` method on your image array directly.

To obtain such values of the desired channels you can Slice them from the image to then query for the values:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('Untitled.png')
hls = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)

#reading Lightness channel: No. 1
#this slice basically means: "give me all rows and all cols from channel 1"
max_value_light = hls[:,:,1].max()
min_value_light = hls[:,:,1].min()

#reading Saturation channel: No. 2
# and this slice means: "give me all rows and all cols from channel 2"
max_value_saturation = hls[:,:,2].max()
min_value_saturation = hls[:,:,2].min()
```

---

*Edit:* Based on your clarification, if you want to query such max/min values, but only those that fall within certain interval `[hue_min, hue_max]` you could use [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) along with max:

```
#obtain the min hue that falls within the interval
#hue is channel 0, so we slice for all x,y pixels and for that channel
theMin = hls[np.where((hls[:,:,0]>hue_min) & (hls[:,:,0]<hue_max))][:,0].min()
#same story with the rest, compare to your _min and _max and use it's index
```

Comment: That is actually not what I meant. I want to get the min / max value where the hue is between range HUE_MIN and HUE_MAX. Can you provide a way for this, too?

Comment: @Spirit so, say your min is 10 and your max is 50... you want the max value (for example 49) that fits between those two, correct?

Comment: Assuming I understand you correctly, that is not what I meant. Clarification:  I "define" a min and max for the hue according to the image histogram. Then I want to "iterate" over each pixel (just not by a for loop) and check: if `hue_min <= hue[x][y] <= hue_max` and get the lowest and highest occurrence of Saturation and Lightness over all pixel where the above statement holds true. Since every pixel consists of three values (Hue, Lightness, Saturation). I hope that clarifies it

Comment: @Spirit well... have you tried the code to see if that is what you meant?... anyways, I see your comment clarifies things up, so I'll enhance my answer shortly :)